# Google indexes only one of 16 articles on my site

Tags: google-search, google-search-console

I've started a new blog (https://sdorra.dev) in the beginning of November 2022 and i submitted it to the google search console at the day it was online.

But only one of the articles (at the moment there are 16 articles online) and the landing page is indexed.
The most of the articles are stuck in "Discovered - currently not indexed" and one is in the "Crawled - currently not indexed" state.

[image: Google Search Console Problem]

[image: Discovered - currently not indexed]

I've read many articles and post to find the problem, but i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

If i search "site:sdorra.dev", only the one indexed article and the landing page is shown. I'm using a sitemap and referenced it in the robots.txt. The inspection tool says "URL is not on Google". "Test Live URL" does not show any errors and request indexing does not help.

The problem exists now for more than 2 months. I'm grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you can add sitemap to your site, and sitemap descriptions in robots.txt

Comment: I already have a [sitemap](https://sdorra.dev/sitemap.xml) and a [robots.txt](https://sdorra.dev/robots.txt).

Answer (score 0):

Your `robots.txt` should look like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Sitemap: https://sdorra.dev/sitemap.xml
```

There exists a [robots.txt tester](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598), which you can use to validate your `robots.txt`.

Comment: Please have a look at my [robots.txt](https://sdorra.dev/robots.txt), as I understand it, this is equivalent to your example.

The robots.txt tester does not work for me. It shows a `Don't see your property? You can add it to your account.` error, but the property for `sdorra.dev` is linked to my account.

Comment: Hm, your `robots.txt` looks fine, your `sitemap.xml` as well. 
Maybe set a higher priority there - like 0.80 instead of 0.64?
And then re-submit the updated `sitemap.xml` to google.

Comment: According to the docs, Google does not consider the element of priority at all. Please have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/build-sitemap#additional-notes-about-xml-sitemaps).

Comment: I've also tried to remove the sitemap from the console, wait until the site gets crawled again and then recreate the sitemap. But that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL Inspection tool in  [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console) to check if your page has been indexed and get recommendations on how to fix any issues.

You can also use the [Google Indexing API](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/quickstart) to quickly submit URLs for indexing.

Comment: I've "request indexing" multiple times and the inspection tool says only "Page is not indexed: Discovered - currently not indexed", there are no recommendations and the live test marks all as good.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a error form google team, they will sove it. Or check the error what is being given by Google serach console.

Comment: The error exists for more than 4 months. The "Live Test" ends with green marks and "URL is available to Google", but the Google Index says "Page is not indexed: Discovered - currently not indexed".